# c# starting from second element in var

Tags: c#

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(filelocation);
                char[] space = { ',' };
                string templine;
                foreach (string line in lines)
                {}
```

how do i do `foreach (string line in lines[1:])` ?
i want to skip the first element and start foreach from the second one

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If you are targeting .NET 3.5 or above, LINQ:

```
foreach (string line in lines.Skip(1)) {...}
```

Although it there is a lot of data, a line-reader may be better, to avoid having to hold all the lines in memory:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> ReadLines(string path) {
    using(var reader = File.OpenText(path)) {
        string line;
        while((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) {
            yield return line;
        }
    }
}
```

then:

```
foreach(var line in ReadLines(filelocation).Skip(1)) {...}
```

Comment: Side note, in .NET 4.0, there is the [`System.IO.File.ReadLines()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx) method that does exactly this.  So you won't have to roll out your own `ReadLines()` implementation.